# Unable to stretch <lightning-button> tag to fill container

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm unable to stretch a `<lightning-button>` to occupy the full width of its container. While applying a *style* of `display: block` or a *class* of `slds-size_12-of-12`, for example, those styles/classes *are* applied to the `<lightning-button>` tag... **however**... when rendered, the tag appears to *wrap* an inner `<button>` tag, and the styles are not transferred to that tag, and it's that inner tag that appears to have all the content.

**EDIT:** The above completely rewritten for clarity

```
<lightning-layout>
    <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow">
        <lightning-button
            label="click me"
            onclick={action}
            class="slds-size_12-of-12">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-layout-item>

    <lightning-layout-item flexibility="no-flex">
        ...
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide code of it ?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi I added an additional screenshot and explanation

Comment: with screenshot you force those who want to help you to manually type code from screenshot. Can you please paste text code instead of  image ?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi You're right. That was dumb. Tired. Code attached. I'll pick this up in the morning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: there's an `slds-button_stretch` class that does exactly this...

Comment: @MarkPond I just discovered the class.. it's new this release.. HOWEVER!.. it doesn't work when applied to the LWC lightning-button tag. I've worked around it by just using a standard button tag and adding the missing SLDS classes. Still... it _should_ work on the LWC tag... but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Many here suggested to use `<button>` instead of `<lightning-button>` as the `slds-button_stretch` class won't apply to it. But here is what you can do to use the `<lightning-button>` provided by salesforce lwc and at the same time stretch it to 100% width.

I insisted to use `<lightning-button>` instead of `<button>` because it's too easy while you want to use a button with an icon in `<lightning-button>` than using a normal `<button>`

Here's what I did to get a button with icon and full width:

```
<lightning-button icon-name="utility:upload" onclick={yourfunction} variant="brand" label="Download" style="display: grid; width: 100%"></lightning-button>
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!